# Programming Atmega8 with AVRISP mkII Error ispProgramMem

Tags: avr, atmega, isp, atmel-studio

If I go to `Tools > Device Programming` in AVRStudio 6.0 to program the Atmega8 everything is working fine. I've set the ISP frequency to 1 MHz and checked the fuses as well.

*But* as I just hit `F5`, programming most of the times failes (sometimes it works for whatever reason) giving me an error message:

[image]

> Error: ispProgramMem: Error status received: Got 0x80, expected 0x00

but unfortunately no further information.

The build output does not report any errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: Blink, Configuration: Debug AVR ------
Build started.
Project "Blink.cproj" (default targets):
Target "PreBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PreBuildEvent)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
Target "CoreBuild" in file "D:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.0\Vs\Compiler.targets" from project "C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\Atmel Studio\Blink\Blink\Blink.cproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
    Task "RunCompilerTask"
        D:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.0\make\make.exe all 
        make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    Done executing task "RunCompilerTask".
    Task "RunOutputFileVerifyTask"
                Program Memory Usage    :   128 bytes   1,6 % Full
                Data Memory Usage       :   0 bytes   0,0 % Full
    Done executing task "RunOutputFileVerifyTask".
Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "Blink.cproj".
Target "PostBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PostBuildEvent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
Target "Build" in file "D:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.0\Vs\Avr.common.targets" from project "C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\Atmel Studio\Blink\Blink\Blink.cproj" (entry point):
Done building target "Build" in project "Blink.cproj".
Done building project "Blink.cproj".

Build succeeded.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: If the chip was using an external oscillator previously and now you are trying to reprogram it without that oscillator - it will not work - put that oscillator back. Check the power lines/connections. Do you have anything connected to the pins that are used for programming?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was debugging with mkii in atmel studio 6 win7 x64. In sudden, after couple of tens flash writes, atmel studio stucked with same error. I resolved issue by playing with frequency of ISP clock in Device Programming Window.

Anthony

Comment: What does "playing" mean here? What did you do to the ISP clock speed that fixed the problem?